# Unity - Scaling down a GameObject containing a child Final IK (VRIK) rig

Tags: unity, inverse-kinematics

I'm currently building a VR / AR hybrid in Unity, where I'm controlling an IK rig using VR, then sending the VR controllers positions to an iOS device using network transforms to mirror the IK rig's movement in ARKit. I'm having trouble implementing pinch to scale the scene locally on the iOS device.

I'm attempting to uniformly scale down a parent GameObject containing the IK rig which has its Head target connected to SteamVR Vive headset and its Hand targets set hand controllers positions. The vectors that describe the positions of the controllers are being sent over the network, so I'm applying the same scale factor to those, so that the targets match up to the scaled down character. However, the IK rig appears to break when scaling the character down, and in particular the legs appear to be too far apart, and the hand movements no longer look correct

Could the problem be to do with the internal relative transforms within the IK rig needing to be modified? And is there a better approach?

Comment: Ever find a fix to this?